# How does the iPhone know you're not a certified service vendor?

Tags: iphone, ios, hardware

I was wondering about how an Apple iPhone “knows” that you aren't a certified service provider when, for example, you replace the battery.

I'm aware that it checks the serial number of the battery when it boots and compares that to the previous battery, but what steps does an "official" service vendor go through to ensure it knows that the replacement was official?

Is there specific hardware that they plug into the Lightning port/pins inside the device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool is called Apple Services Toolkit and it uses the network connection on the iPhone (or Mac or iPad) to validate the parts before and after the repair with Apple servers online.

Apple has had private and internal service software for decades and the latest iPhone iteration is cloud based. It performs advanced data collection and diagnostics and most importantly has the ability to re-serialize components like batteries and TouchID sensors to the logic board. Apple service parts are traditionally not serialized and are written to permanently as part of the repair confirmation process once testing is complete.

<sup>A little trivia… This is not an Apple invention.  BMW has been serializing components like power window motors to the BCM (body control module - a computer) since the late 1990s. To make these replaced parts work, you needed a their software running on a Unix laptop with an ODB-II interface cable.</sup>

To gain access to this tool, you have to be an authorized service provider and [have an active account](https://gsx2.apple.com) with their parts supplier program (GSX) to ensure only “Apple approved” parts are used.

iFixit.com has an excellent blog post called [*Here are the Tools Apple Won’t Let You Have*](https://www.ifixit.com/News/33593/heres-the-secret-repair-tool-apple-wont-let-you-have) that goes into depth on these tools and how they work.

Comment: Is the serial number on a battery read-only after it's installed and verified? Or could it potentially be changed if you had low-level access?

Comment: The SN# is embedded on the battery controller.  It could potentially be changed, but a direct examination of the chip on the controller board would be necessary as a first step.  If it *not* an EEPROM, then no, it won’t be able to be changed.

Comment: I've removed some comments - please avoid extended discussion that's not related to improving the post. Posting alternative answers or opinions about Apple aren't constructive in comments. Discussing posts is better placed in [chat rooms like this one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat).